# Upgrade Debian release 7.11 (wheezy) to 8.5 (jessie)

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, upgrade, debian-jessie

I have a Debian system (virtual development box, not reachable from the internet) which has not been updated for a while.  Now I'd like to make up for this, but it seems the sources are not available any more:

```
$ sudo -s
> LANG=C apt-get update
...
Ign http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports/non-free Translation-de_DE
Err http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports/main amd64 Packages
  301  Moved Permanently [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
Err http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
  301  Moved Permanently [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
Err http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
  301  Moved Permanently [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
Fetched 13.5 kB in 8s (1512 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/dists/squeeze-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  301  Moved Permanently [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/dists/squeeze-backports/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  301  Moved Permanently [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/dists/squeeze-backports/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  301  Moved Permanently [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I was able to `dist-upgrade` from 7.4 to 7.11 today, but this seems to be all I can get.

Is there a way to successfully `update` and `dist-upgrade` my system to Debian 8, Jessie?  My main goal is to get apache 2.4 that way.

**Update:**
Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, empty and commented-out lines removed:

```
deb http://debian.uni-duisburg-essen.de/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://debian.uni-duisburg-essen.de/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://debian.uni-duisburg-essen.de/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://debian.uni-duisburg-essen.de/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian wheezy svn18
```

Comment: try `apt-get update --fix-missing` then `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: If you're using Debian 7 (wheezy), why are you still using squeeze-backports?

Comment: Good point! I commented out the `squeeze-backports`. Now the error messages have gone, but I `apt-get dist-upgrade` still doesn't lift me to Jessie.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` is just a glorified `apt-get upgrade` on steroids. Show us your `grep -REh '^[^#].*$' /etc/apt/sources.list*`. (That gives all non-empty lines starting with something other than `#`.)

Comment: I updated my question with the `sources.list` info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading to Debian 8 Jessie is more complicated than simply running `dist-upgrade`.  I’ll summarise the steps involved but I’d
strongly suggest that you fully familiarise yourself with [Upgrades from Debian 7 (wheezy)](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) from the **Release Notes for Debian 8 (jessie)**.

1. Configure the package repositories.

   You modify the configuration file for package repositories, `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include the URLs for the repositories for Jessie. It should include entries similar to:

   ```
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
   deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
   deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

   deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
   ```

   See [Preparing sources for APT](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrade-process)
2. Get the list of available packages for Jessie:

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
3. Ensure you have enough disk space to download all the new packages. Then, upgrade the packages which can be upgraded without requiring any other packages to be removed or installed:

   ```
   apt-get upgrade
   ```

   This should have carried out a *minimal upgrade* which installs a new kernel and udev.
4. **Reboot** the system to use the new kernel.
5. Complete the process by upgrading the remaining packages:

   ```
   apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

Comment: Phew - looks like a lot of work! Ok, I'll look into this ...

Comment: Ok, I did it, and apparently everything worked. I simply replaced all `wheezy` in my `sources.list` by `jessie`, and `svn18` by `svn19`. I had some hassle retracing the changes in my `etckeeper` - seems some symlinks were replaced by directories -, thus it will probably be wise to to this after every `apt-get` action.

Comment: @Tobias Glad to hear that it worked out for you.