# debian version wheezy or jessie

Tags: debian

I am working on a server, not able to ask the former admin about this server.

it's a debian server.

uname -or gives 3.2.0-4-amd64 GNU/Linux
seem to indicate wheezy: https://packages.debian.org/nl/wheezy/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64

when I do cat/etc/debian_version it gives: jessie/sid
so indicates debian 8

however all sources.list show wheezy (debian 7)

There are some things not working quit well, so things seem to be screwed up ..... what should I do here? dist-upgrade?

Comment: Can you how an extract of `dpkg -l` ?

Comment: I'd start from doing a backup (at least at file level via `rsync`) and try `apt-get -f install`, `apt-get update`; `apt-get upgrade`; `apt-get dist-upgrade` without changing sources.list.

Comment: body is limited I get when I want to pastethe output of 'dpkg -l' in here (too long list)

Comment: weird sudo apt-get dist-upgrade says .... 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded...... should I just replace the wheezy in sources.list in to jessie?

Comment: Take a backup of all critical data, restore it onto a reasonably-configured server, and then shoot this disaster of frankenserver in the head.

Comment: Not that easy to reinstall... it is in a corporate server room. Need to go there with a dvd play er. ... otherwhise i wpuld agrree

Comment: And can the minus voter tell me why?

Comment: might follow this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/783608/upgrade-debian-release-7-11-wheezy-to-8-5-jessie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this link:

[Upgrade Debian release 7.11 (wheezy) to 8.5 (jessie)](https://serverfault.com/questions/783608/upgrade-debian-release-7-11-wheezy-to-8-5-jessie)

and added this to /ect/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

after this did a apt-get update and apt-get upgrade

this installed a lot of stuff

than rebooted....

and this seem to work already better.

now I find:

uname -r

3.2.0-4-amd64

sudo cat /etc/debian_version

8.5

and after this I did the dist-upgrade:

now:

uname -r

3.16.0-4-amd64

sudo cat /etc/debian_version

8.5

And now everything seem to work just fine again!